# Blender : AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'scene'

Tags: python, blender

When running my script, I get this error:

> AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'scene'

I'm trying to create a script for optimization:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Empic Stone",
    "author": "Null",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "VIEW3D > ADD > Mesh",
    "description": "Empic Stone",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh"
}

# Imports
import bpy

# Mesh - Create Cubic
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.00, 0.00, 1.00))

def draw_item(self, context):
     self.layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
     self.layout.operator(EpicStone.bl_idname, text="Epic Stone", icon="PLUGIN")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(draw_item)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(draw_item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     register()
```

Comment: if you post the entire trace back we can probably help but `_RestrictContext` appears nowhere in your code so we have no idea where to start.. also possibly include your imports so we know what libraries you are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying this script is intended for blender would probably help people. I've worked with it and this is the only reason why I recognized it. Anyway, normally this kind of error happens since Blender restricts access to bpy.context and bpy.data. This is from the [documentation](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes/#Restricted_Context):

> This is done because there is no assurance that the data loaded when
> the addon is registered will be active or even exist when the user
> accesses operators the addon defines.
> If you see an exception like this, then the addon needs to be updated to access the context during execution rather then on registration:

Now rather than "reinvent the wheel", please follow the above link and follow their code.

Comment: Solved. Thanks very much!

Comment: Maybe you could suggest an edit on my answer on your particular case with the code you use. it would close the question better.

Comment: This answer helped me, but to be more specific: you can't be execute Blender operations, such as adding models or opening images, until your Add-on is fully registered